# OpenGL ES Questions (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm planning on making a new game with OpenGL for the iPhone, but I first have a couple questions.  First of all, I'm stuck between choosing OpenGL 1.1 or 2.0 (I know this question has been asked before, though I feel mine is a bit different).  I know that OpenGL 1.1 is compatible on all devices and and is a fixed-pipeline (it's easy to learn).  I know that 2.0 is a programmable-pipeline (it's harder).

I'm an indie developer who plans on making a **2D game** with OpenGL ES.  I know that OpenGL ES 1.1 will be much easier,though tutorials for 1.1 are hard to find.  2.0 is a lot harder but tutorials are everywhere.  I recently purchased "Learning iOS Game Programming", which, despite its name, is partially outdated (though teaches 1.1).

Bottom line: 1.1 or 2.0.  I want to get my app out as soon as possible.  Also, if anyone knows any good books/tutorials, your feedback is welcome.

Comment: Why not throw caution to the wind and forget OpenGL all together and go with either the standard stuff to display images, or Cocos2D? Or maybe even Corona (yet it costs money)?

Comment: @anon Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not a big fan of Cocos2D (It just doesn't feel right to me).  Also, displaying images is a good thought, but how exactly would that work? Wouldn't that slow down the device?

Comment: In regards to OpenGL ES 1.1 vs 2.0 examples, there are far, far more 1.1 examples out there than 2.0 ones because of how long it's been supported.  Only now are more 2.0 resources becoming available.  You might not be looking in the right places if you're missing all the 1.1 stuff out there.

Comment: If you're looking to get your application out as soon as possible, OpenGL ES is probably not the best approach for you.  You're probably better off with a framework like cocos2D or even using Core Animation, both of which will save a tremendous amount of code over writing a 2-D engine for OpenGL ES yourself.

Comment: @Brad Larson Thanks for the suggestions, but I still don't want to use 3rd party software to make apps.  About using CA: it sounds like a good idea because most of my game is just moving images, but I also need to use particles and collision detection.  Also, how would I give UIImages AI?

Comment: @Andy - OpenGL ES won't give you AI or collision detection either.  Both it and Core Animation are simply display technologies.  That code will be up to you, or you'll need to use a third-party framework like Box2D.  I'm just saying that Core Animation will be easier to use for moving 2-D images around than OpenGL ES.

Comment: @Brad Larson Sorry to ask a lot of questions, this will be me (hopefully) last one.  I forgot to mention that my game wil involve enemies, many moving objects, and is similar to the classic game of Asteroids (Though with better graphics).  Will CA still be the best route for performance?

Comment: @Andy - If it's an Asteroids-style game you're after, perhaps this might be of interest to you: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/02/asteroids-style-game-in-coreanimation.html .  While that's targeted at the Mac, the same principles will apply on iOS, because Core Animation is nearly identical between the two platforms.

Answer (score 1):

This guy has some pretty good video tutorials, actual game code, and actually let's you use his code(for a real game it needs work).

http://www.71squared.com/iphone-tutorials/

You get, particle systems, spritesheets, sound class, game states, etc

For a starter on gl-es 1.1 it's good.

If it all sounds too much, try a engine, if not, learn from the tuts and do your version, preferably not using objects, C structs and the like are much more easy on the ram.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, these tutorials seem pretty helpful but do you  know if they are up to date or not? Thanks.

Comment: They are up to date on most things, stuff related to interface and Xcode is a bit dated

Comment: Forgot to mention I was actually using the particle code up to a few months back, until I rolled my own, I still use the program he sells to create particle systems (basically creates a XML with the params), it's nice to have the interface, I have added more stuff, but I get to see the basic with the software. (by the way no relation with the guy)